# how to replace '&' and '()' in sql query for oracle using regex

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle10g

I have columns in my database which have & and ()

I want to replace '&' with word 'and'
'()' with word 'bracket'

is it possible to do in oracle using regex?

Thanks

Comment: what have you try? show us sample data and expected output

Comment: You can refer this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126127/replace-special-characters-in-a-column-with-space

Answer (score 0):

Taking your requirement verbatim, I don't see any reason why `REPLACE` would not work here:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET someCol = REPLACE(REPLACE(someCol, '()', 'bracket'), '&', 'and')
```

If you wanted to do a regex replace, then you might have to deal with your characters being metacharacters, and therefore requiring escaping.